# Razor checkboxes for list of models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

**User Model**

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserPets> UserPets { get; set; }
}
```

**User Pets Model**

```
public class UserPetsModel
{
    public PetModel Pet{ get; set; }
    public bool UserHasPet { get; set; }
}
```

Using these 2 models I am creating an edit page where a User can come in and edit which Pets they have.

To enable them to state which pets they have I am trying to use checkboxes.

**Edit Page**

```
@model Models.UserModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Model.FirstName
   </div>

    @foreach (var userPets in Model.UserPets)
    {
        @Model.Pet.AnimalName
        <div>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => userPets .UserHasPet)
        </div>
    }

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The problem I am having is when trying to map the `UserModel` back to the controller action. When I press the save button, everything on the `UserModel` is being mapped back to the controller apart from the `UserPetsModels` which I believe is due to the use of the foreach.

Is there another way in which I can display a checkbox for each `UserPetModel` without using a foreach or a for loop.

Comment: change it to for loop, as model binder needs indexing for list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. You should create [**EditorTemplate**](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm) for your `UserPetsModel`. It will look like:

```
 @model UserPetsModel

 @Model.Pet.AnimalName
 <div>
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.UserHasPet)
 </div>
```

And then you can simply do:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPets)
```

`EditorFor` will create right binding for you. Note that you should create **EditorTemplate** only for `UserPets` and it also will work for `List<UserPetsModel>` and `IEnumarable<UserPetsModel>` with the same syntax that i show.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest replace the loop with EditorTemplate. So your

```
@foreach (var userPets in Model.UserPets)
    {
        @Model.Pet.AnimalName
        <div>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => userPets.UserHasPet)
        </div>
    }
```

would look like:

```
   <div class="row">
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserPets)
   </div>
```

And define a view in (~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/UserPets.cshtml) like:

```
@model UserPetsModel
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Pet.PetId)

@Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserHasPet, Model.Pet.AnimalName)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.UserHasPet)
```